# Remove "Time to upgrade" message from dashboard

Tags: wp-admin, updates

So far I've been using the following code to remove the dashboard update message ("WordPress 3.5 is available! Please update now."):

```
remove_action('wp_version_check', 'wp_version_check');
remove_action('admin_init', '_maybe_update_core');
add_filter('pre_transient_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;"));
```

However, it doesn't seem to work any more with current WordPress versions. Is there a new way to removing this message that is compatible with later WordPress versions?

Comment: When asking such questions, please note, what you mean with "current WordPress versions".

Comment: Ok. I'm using WP 3.4.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## How to hide WordPress update mesages

### CSS

The low-tech way to hide something is using css:

```
// Low-tech hiding of update-mesages
// source: http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/hide-update-nag-within-the-admin/
function remove_upgrade_nag() {
   echo '<style type="text/css">
           .update-nag {display: none}
         </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'remove_upgrade_nag');
```

This more-or-less works, but it is a lot of work to find al the places WordPress shows messages.

### Add_action

A better way is using actions. The wordpress-core (core in this context is WordPress itself) update messages are triggered in `wp-admin/includes/update.php`, line 84 core_update_footer, and line 139 with the great name update_nag. We can use actions to disable these:

```
//hide core updates notification in the dashboard
function hide_wp_update_nag() {
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 ); //update notice at the top of the screen
    remove_filter( 'update_footer', 'core_update_footer' ); //update notice in the footer
}
add_action('admin_menu','hide_wp_update_nag');
```

As an alternative to:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
```

You might want to use, for multi-site:

```
add_action( 'network_admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
```

The dashboard notifications are a bit harder, bit this should do the job:

```
//hide plugin updates notification in the dashboard
function hide_plugin_update_indicator(){
    global $menu,$submenu;
    $menu[65][0] = 'Plugins';
    $submenu['index.php'][10][0] = 'Updates';
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'hide_plugin_update_indicator');
```

Although the update notices are hidden, it is still possible to see that something needs to be updated on the following pages (and do the updates):

- /wp-admin/update-core.php
- /wp-admin/themes.php
- /wp-admin/plugins.php

### Disabling updates

If you completely want to disable updates, use:

```
//http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_core', create_function('$a', "return null;")); // disable core update
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_plugins', create_function('$a', "return null;")); // disable plugin update
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_themes', create_function('$a', "return null;")); // disable theme update
```

This will completely disable updates for core, plugins and themes.

### Plugins

You might put this code in a [functionality](http://www.doitwithwp.com/create-functions-plugin/) [plugin](http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-create-a-functionality-plugin/#.UNscxjs8ZCc), so it works in all themes.

Some ready-made plugins:

- [No update nag plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/no-update-nag/) can do (some of) this for you as well
- [Disable WordPress Core Updates](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-wordpress-core-update/)

### Bonus

To find out how to exclude specific plugins from updating:

- [Excluding your plugin or theme from update checks](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/14/excluding-your-plugin-or-theme-from-update-checks/)
- [Plugin update hider](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-update-hider/)

Comment: Don't do the pre_site_transient_ filters, it forces continuous checks for updates (although they don't get displayed).  A [better approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821419/wordpress-plugin-notifications/14935077) hides the messages but avoids the overhead.