# To remove plugin notices for non-admin users

Tags: plugins

How to hide/disable any plugin notices for non admin users in dashboard? Can you please help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to hide the notifications via CSS, see below:

```
    function hide_update_msg_non_admins(){
     if (!current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) { // non-admin users
            echo '<style>#setting-error-tgmpa>.updated settings-error notice is-dismissible, .update-nag, .updated { display: none; }</style>';
        }
    }
    add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_update_msg_non_admins');
```

A more detailed answer can be found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76503/remove-time-to-upgrade-message-from-dashboard).

Comment: Hi Adrian! Thanks for your response. However,I have tried using your snippets. It didn't work for me. Non admin user (Editor for my case) can still see some plugin notices.(It says the user don't have permission to install that plugin). I want to hide this types of message for any user other than admin. Any suggestion? Thanks again.

Comment: I have slightly modified your snippet and it worked perfectly for me. Thanks.
    function hide_update_msg_non_admins(){
     if (!current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) {
     echo '<style>#setting-error-tgmpa>.updated settings-error notice is-dismissible, .update-nag, .updated { display: none; }</style>';
        }
    }
    add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_update_msg_non_admins');

Comment: Great, I've updated the code! Please mark my answer as approved.

Comment: Please @NizamUddinSikder mark Adrian_Spiac as the correct answer to help others without wasting time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following piece of code in your functions.php

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
} else {
echo ".update-nag , .error, .updated{ display:none; }";
}
```

Comment: It will hide notices & warnings for all non-admin users

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_only_warnings');

function admin_only_warnings() {
if(is_admin() && !current_user_can('administrator') ) {
  echo '<style>
    <!-- add your classes/ids below -->
    .warning, .error, .updated {display:none !important;}
    } 
  </style>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
function am_disable_admin_notices() {
global $wp_filter;
if (!current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) {
    if (isset($wp_filter['user_admin_notices'])) {
            unset( $wp_filter['user_admin_notices']);
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'am_disable_admin_notices' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution on Kingsta. I prefer do not interfere to admin CSS.

// Hide dashboard update notifications for non-admin users
function kinsta_hide_update_nag() {
if ( ! current_user_can( 'update_core' ) ) {
remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
}
}

add_action('admin_menu','kinsta_hide_update_nag');

Source:
https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-wordpress-update-notification/